# iOS: Date Components Inquiry

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, notifications

I was wondering how I would edit the `dateComps setDay:` to go off 3 days before the date set in the picker. I typed in -3, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.
Any help is much appreciated! Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)scheduleNotifButton:(id)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:13];
    [dateComps setMinute:30];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Event is in 3 days!";
    localNotif.alertAction = nil;

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the great answers! It's going to be hard to pick which one is correct since each one is perfect! Either way, thank you everyone so much, you have helped me out tremendously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you have typed `-3`, do you mean you used this line?

```
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day] - 3];
```

This should in fact work.

Also, you can tell the system to fire any next year by just settings the current year to the date components. You can find the current year just the way you found the date components for `pickerDate`.

After that, you can set the `repeatInterval` of the local notification to `NSYearCalendarUnit`, that way it will fire each year.

Comment: What if day starts as 2 or 1? This will result in setDay: being called with a negative number. Is that valid?

Comment: @nielsbot +1 I was going to post the same line of code gcamp did aside from that very question.

Comment: @gcamp +1, I found an example where it's used in Apple docs ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3), Listing 10).

Comment: Yes, it's valid. `NSCalendar` will make the necessary calculations if the value is not valid by itself (like -1 day or 46 days). http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3

Comment: @darvids0n Ha, you got it first :P

Comment: @gcamp: For the example you linked you have to make a new NSDateComponents object (call it `delta`) with days == -3, then call `-[NSDate dateByAddingComponents:delta]`. You can not just call setDays to a negative value on the original `NSDate`

Comment: @nielsbot He doesn't. `dateComps` is an `NSDateComponents` in the OP.

Comment: @gcamp Awesome, thank you so much! I was simply typing in `[dateComps setDay:- 3];` Thank you so much for your help. And also, I'm unsure of what code to use to have it ignore the year. This is supposed to alert the user of approaching birthdays, so if the year is 1980 I don't think it will fire. Do you know how I should set the `[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];`? Maybe `[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]=nil];`?

Comment: @Joey502 Create a new date components and don't set the year at *all*. That should work. Exact quotation from the Apple docs (I am not making [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470) up): `You may want to create a date object without components such as years—to store your friend’s birthday, for instance. While it is not technically possible to create a yearless date, you can use date components to create a date object without a specified year` :P

Comment: @darvids0n Awesome thanks for that! So should I just not type `[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];` in at all, or just leave it as it is? Sorry for the beginner question!

Comment: @darvids0n Cool thanks man. Yeah I deleted [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]]; from my code, set everything up, but the notification didn't fire like it usually does, it fired instantly when I pushed the button. Then, I deleted both that and NSYearCalendarUnit from the date comp, it did the same thing, it's pretty odd

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is subtract 3 days from the date returned by the date picker, no?

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date]
pickerDate = [ pickerDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3 * 24 * 60 * 60 ] ; // add this line
```

Version using date components:

```
- (IBAction)scheduleNotifButton:(id)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    {
        NSDateComponent * deltaComponents = [ [ NSDateComponents alloc ] init ];
        deltaComponents.days = -3 ;

        pickerDate = [ pickerDate dateByAddingComponents:deltaComponents ] ;
    }

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:pickerDate];

    [dateComps setHour:13];
    [dateComps setMinute:30];

    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Event is in 3 days!";
    localNotif.alertAction = nil;

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}
```

Comment: Also, you want the alarm to go off 3 days before the event at 1:30 pm correct? I don't know why you extract the seconds and set them on `dateComps`... I'd just skip the creation of `timeComps` and set seconds to 0.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! So, I should skip setting everything in the time comps, and just add your code to it? Sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: This could be potentially not valid since `24 * 60 * 60` doesn't always equal one day (leap year, day time saving). There's also could be specifics to calendar that aren't the Gregorian.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to subtract 3 days from Today(NOW). You can adapt it for your needs:

```
   NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"NOW:%@",today);
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *todayComps = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
     todayComps.day -=3;
    NSDate *dateMinus3Days = [gregorian dateFromComponents:todayComps];
    NSLog(@"3 days before NOW:%@",dateMinus3Days);
```

Your making it too complicated. DateComponents can be modified and then set to a new date.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a)

```
// ...
NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
[offset setDay:(-3)];
NSDate *date3DaysBefore = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:pickerDate options:0];
// ...
```